# Hyperledger Febric Error : Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I was trying to run `fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/application-javascript/app.js` file
but got discovery error.

[It is showing discovery error after I gave command "node app.js"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dowl0.png)

Comment: check your peer logs

Comment: If the error is written in text format, it should be written in text format. Not an image. See the guide below on Stack Overflow. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / [do-not-upload-image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Delete

- user.id
- appUser.id

identities from your `/home/pritam/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/application-javascript/wallet` directory.

The error that occurred is already documented in the `app.js` file that exists under the `asset-transfer-basic` directory:

```
// NOTE: If you see  kind an error like these:
/*
    2020-08-07T20:23:17.590Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: send[mychannel] - Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied
    ******** FAILED to run the application: Error: DiscoveryService: mychannel error: access denied

   OR

   Failed to register user : Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[ { code: 20, message: 'Authentication failure' } ]]
   ******** FAILED to run the application: Error: Identity not found in wallet: appUser
*/
// Delete the /fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/application-javascript/wallet directory
// and retry this application.
//
// The certificate authority must have been restarted and the saved certificates for the
// admin and application user are not valid. Deleting the wallet store will force these to be reset
// with the new certificate authority.
```